# Kafka to Snowflake connection issue

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ksqldb

I am trying to connect from local standalone Confluent Kafka topics to Snowflake tables. I am using the following connector config via `ksqldb`.

```
CREATE SINK CONNECTOR `snowflake_sink` WITH(
"name"='snowflake_sink',
"tasks.max"='1',
"connector.class"='com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector',
"topics"='USERPROFILE',
"snowflake.url.name"='https://mybu.mycompany.us-east-1.aws.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com',
"snowflake.user.name”=‘myuser’,
"snowflake.database.name"='DEMO_DB',
"snowflake.topic2table.map"='USERPROFILE:UK_SF_DB1_Table1',
"snowflake.schema.name"='PUBLIC',
"snowflake.private.key”=‘<valid private key>’,
"snowflake.private.key.passphrase”=‘<valid pass phrase>’,
"key.converter"='org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter',
"value.converter"='com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter',
"key.converter.schema.registry.url"='http://schema-registry:8081',
"value.converter.schema.registry.url"='http://schema-registry:8081');
```

Ksqldb throws error saying snowflake url, username, private key is not valid. They are all valid as I can login using the same via Snowflake web ui.

Comment: This is the same question as:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049202/snowflake-kafka-connector-cant-login

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas on troubleshooting this:

1. it looks like you have some "smart quotes" in your config, please remove the smart single and double quotes and replace them with proper text quotes.  This may have happened during your preparing of this question, so just double check them.
2. set your table name to all capital letters.
3. your snowflake account should not include the https:// prefix. Examples at these links:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Docker-Compose-Setting-up-Kafka-using-Snowflake-Sink-Connector-and-testing-Streams

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html

Comment: can you please help me correct URL will it be -> https://mycompany.us-east-1.aws.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com or it needs privatelink in the URL something else?

Comment: it should be the URL of the web user interface, without the https://

Comment: if you're still not sure, you can login to the webUI, run the following (documented at this link) and use the entry for SNOWFLAKE_DEPLOYMENT in the record returned.   select system$whitelist_privatelink();
   
 https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_whitelist_privatelink.html#examples

Comment: I am using the url of web interface like I mentioned in the question I got confused by you saying we have to remove prefix. If you take a look at my url in question I tried it without https it doesn't work.

Comment: the examples we have in the documentation look like this: xy12345.us-west-2.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com or myaccount.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com:443 (no privatelink, but has 443 for the port).  Notice how there is no .aws. in the url, like you have.   Another thing to check, perhaps there is an issue with your key or passphrase, to check that I'd suggest you login to the webUI and query the information_schema.login_history to see if that provides you failed attempts.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/login_history.html

Comment: From: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html
"the https:// and port number are optional."

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the smart quotes and use the normal one like
'snowflake.url.name'='my.domain.com:443',