# Snowflake Kafka connector, can't login

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use the Kafka Connect sink connector for Snowflake following instructions here: [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html#distributed-mode). I can see in Snowflake that the account I created can successfully login via public key auth, however I only get this error message from the Connect API:

```
{
  "error_code": 400,
  "message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 3 error(s):\nsnowflake.url.name: Cannot connect to Snowflake\nsnowflake.user.name: Cannot connect to Snowflake\nsnowflake.private.key: Cannot connect to Snowflake\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"
}
```

This is the connector config:

```
{
  "name": "sink_TEST",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "test_topic",
    "buffer.count.records": "10000",
    "buffer.flush.time": "60",
    "buffer.size.bytes": "5000000",
    "snowflake.url.name": "my_account.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com:443",
    "snowflake.user.name":"sink_user",
    "snowflake.database.name": "test-database",
    "snowflake.schema.name": "PUBLIC",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "snowflake.private.key": "someprivatekey",
    "value.converter": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Can you contact Snowflake Support? Not sure we can help you here without your actual account information

Comment: According to the docs, there is a passphrase for your private key https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer I didn't apply a passphrase to the key. The weird thing is as step 1 I immediately checked snowflake to see if the login succeeded with the key and according to entries in snowflake, login did succeed.

Comment: Perhaps the answer here might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655145/kafka-to-snowflake-connection-issue?rq=1